# Stop Audio playback in JavaScript, audio continues playing after changing state to SUCCESS

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I'm facing an issue with audio playback in my JavaScript code. I have a function xState that handles changing states based on certain conditions, and I'm using audio to provide feedback. The audio should play when the state is DANGER and stop when the state changes to SUCCESS.

I've implemented the logic to play and stop the audio based on the state, and it seems to work fine for playing the audio. However, when the state changes to SUCCESS, the audio keeps playing instead of stopping.

`const audioStates = { Head: false, Body: false, Distance: false, Height: false, };`

````
const xState = ({
            name,
            value,
            threshold,
            timer,
            currentState,
            currentStateTimeStamp,
            cbCurrentStateTimeStamp,
            cbChange,
            toastMsgSuccess,
            toastMsgDanger,
          }) => {
            let status = statesName.SUCCESS;
            let audioInterval = null;
            if (value <= threshold) {
              timer.reset();
              status = statesName.SUCCESS;
            } else if (value > threshold) {
              timer.start({ precision: 'secondTenths' });
              if (
                timer.getTotalTimeValues().seconds >
                appContext.timer_timeUntilBadPosture
              ) {
                status = statesName.DANGER;
              } else {
                status = statesName.WARNING;
              }
            }
            function playAudioForState(state) {
              switch (state) {
                case 'Head':
                  dangerAudioHead.play();
                  break;
                case 'Body':
                  dangerAudioBody.play();
                  break;
                case 'Distance':
                  dangerAudioDistance.play();
                  break;
                case 'Height':
                  dangerAudioHeight.play();
                  break;
                default:
                  break;
              }
              // Update the audio state to true
              audioStates[name] = true;
            }
            function stopAudioForState(state) {
              switch (state) {
                case 'Head':
                  dangerAudioHead.pause();
                  dangerAudioHead.currentTime = 0;
                  break;
                case 'Body':
                  dangerAudioBody.pause();
                  dangerAudioBody.currentTime = 0;
                  break;
                case 'Distance':
                  dangerAudioDistance.pause();
                  dangerAudioDistance.currentTime = 0;
                  break;
                case 'Height':
                  dangerAudioHeight.pause();
                  dangerAudioHeight.currentTime = 0;
                  break;
                default:
                  break;
              }
              // Update the audio state to false
              audioStates[name] = false;
            }
            if (currentState !== status) {
              setTimelineData([
                ...timelineData,
                [
                  name,
                  currentState,
                  statesColourHex[currentState],
                  currentStateTimeStamp,
                  nextObj.createdAt,
                ],
              ]);
              cbCurrentStateTimeStamp(nextObj.createdAt);
              if (status === statesName.SUCCESS) {
                if (status === statesName.SUCCESS) {
                  stopAudioForState(name);
                  audioStates[name] = false;
                  showToast(toastMsgSuccess, Intent.SUCCESS);
                  if (audioInterval !== null) {
                    clearInterval(audioInterval);
                    audioInterval = null;
                  }
                }
              } else if (status === statesName.DANGER) {
                if (!audioInterval && !audioStates[name]) {
                  audioStates[name] = true;
                  playAudioForState(name);
                  // Create an interval to play audio every 3 seconds
                  audioInterval = setInterval(() => {
                    playAudioForState(name);
                  }, 3000);
                }
                showToast(toastMsgDanger, Intent.DANGER);
              } else if (status === statesName.WARNING) {
                // Stop the audio interval if it's active when in WARNING state
                if (audioInterval !== null) {
                  clearInterval(audioInterval);
                  audioInterval = null;
                }
              }
              cbChange(status);
            }
          };```
````

Answer (score 1):

Your `audioInterval` variable is scoped too deep, so it isn't being remembered between function calls. Here's an abridged version of your code:

```
const xState = () => {
  let status = statesName.SUCCESS;
  let audioInterval = null;
  if (currentState !== status) {
    cbCurrentStateTimeStamp(nextObj.createdAt);
    if (status === statesName.SUCCESS) {
      if (status === statesName.SUCCESS) {
        if (audioInterval !== null) {
          clearInterval(audioInterval);
          audioInterval = null;
```

`audioInterval` is created and discarded each time you call the xState function, so the previously set interval will never be cleared because you no longer have a reference to it.

You can fix this by storing `audioInterval` somewhere outside the xState function.

Comment: I've changed it according to what you told me, but the audio still won't stop